# Word Automation in C#. Error while using SaveAs

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am getting the following error when trying to `Save as Document Object` while trying to implement a word automation in C#:

> ```
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> ```
>
> (0x80020005): Type mismatch.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005
>   (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
>
> ```
>    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.SaveAs(Object&
> ```
>
> FileName, Object& FileFormat, Object&
>   LockComments, Object& Password,
>   Object& AddToRecentFiles, Object&
>   WritePassword, Object&
>   ReadOnlyRecommended, Object&
>   EmbedTrueTypeFonts, Object&
>   SaveNativePictureFormat, Object&
>   SaveFormsData, Object&
>   SaveAsAOCELetter, Object& Encoding,
>   Object& InsertLineBreaks, Object&
>   AllowSubstitutions, Object&
>   LineEnding, Object& AddBiDiMarks)
>
> ```
>    at TestWordAutomation.Form1.SaveAs(String
> ```
>
> fileName) in
>   D:\dotnet\WordAutomation\TestWordAutomation\TestWordAutomation\Form1.cs:line
>   246
>
> ```
>    at TestWordAutomation.Form1.button4_Click(Object
> ```
>
> sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\dotnet\WordAutomation\TestWordAutomation\TestWordAutomation\Form1.cs:line
>   557

I am calling the `Save As` method like so:

```
MySaveAs("Doc1.doc");
MySaveAs("Doc2.doc");
MySaveAs("Doc3.doc");

//I have a MySaveAs function
 public void  MySaveAs(string fileName)
        {
            object FileName = null, FileFormat = null, LockComments = null, _Password = null, AddToRecentFiles = null, _WritePassword = null, _ReadOnlyRecommended = null, _EmbedTrueTypeFonts = null, SaveNativePictureFormat = null, _SaveFormsData = null, SaveAsAOCELetter = null, Encoding = null, InsertLineBreaks = null, AllowSubstitutions = null, LineEnding = null, AddBiDiMarks = null;
            FileName = (object) fileName;
            oDoc.SaveAs(ref FileName, ref FileFormat, ref LockComments, ref _Password, ref AddToRecentFiles,
                        ref _WritePassword, ref _ReadOnlyRecommended, ref _EmbedTrueTypeFonts,
                        ref SaveNativePictureFormat, ref _SaveFormsData, ref SaveAsAOCELetter, ref Encoding,
                        ref InsertLineBreaks, ref AllowSubstitutions, ref LineEnding, ref AddBiDiMarks);
        }
```

Can any one help me to resolve this ?

Comment: Please do not close/delete; this question is part of an open SO Bug: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/134204-markdown-bug-with-firefox-3-0-6

Answer (score 8):

'Tis painful. I remember getting that working with the Word/Excel Interop. Not to be flippant, but one of the parameters has an incorrect type. Hopefully the following helps, but I did a number of these types of definitions.

```
static object s_missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
static object s_true = true;
static object s_false = false;
static object s_forcesave = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges;

static Word._Application s_app = null;
...
return s_app.Documents.Open ( ref filename,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing,
   ref s_missing );
```

Comment: Setting all needed ref missing parameters helped me to get rid with COMExceptions. I agree it burns eyes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass null into any of the interop function call - use Missing.Value instead (as suggested by Kenny)

Comment: Should be a comment to @kenny 's answer ?